# npm install printer not working

Tags: node.js, printing, npm, node-webkit

While i am trying to install printer (npm install printer) i am getting this error.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform
.Targets(23,7): error MSB8007: The Platform for project 'node_printer.vcxproj'
is invalid.  Platform='x64'. You may be seeing this message because you are try
ing to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-defaul
t Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [D:\node\printer\node_modules\p
rinter\build\node_printer.vcxproj]
```

Anyone please help me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First install node-gyp

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

then install any **python** version between **2.7.0 to 3.0.0**

goto *printer* folder in node_modules and node-gyp rebuild as shown below

```
cd node_module/printer
node-gyp rebuild
```

Comment: While installing, npm install printer i am getting this error. There is no such folder available in node_modules because npm installation stopped due to this error.

Comment: i have cloned then npm install not working showing same error

Comment: after cloning, run the 'node-grp rebuild' command inside the node-printer folder

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error itself :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform
.Targets(23,7): error MSB8007: The Platform for project 'node_printer.vcxproj'
is invalid. Platform='x64'.
```

It may be that the module only works with x86 (x32) Windows installations. Personally, I doubt it, but it may be possible.

Also, as said above, installing **python** may solve your problem. (Check sources, there is at least one *.py* file). Reinstalling *node-gyp* shouldn't make any difference since the npm install should take care of that. Hope you get it fixed.

Comment: i have installed pythan but still issue not fixed